# ChakraUI useColorModeValue not updating main box color

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

New to react and playing around with ChakraUI. I'm using their `useColorModeValue` property on my main `<Box>` container. Though, it's not actually changing it's color, the toggle works fine for everything else, just not this box.

```
import {
  ChakraProvider,
  Box,
  Text,
  Link,
  VStack,
  Grid,
  Theme,
  useColorModeValue,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';

function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
        <Box minH='100vh' bg={useColorModeValue('brand.500', 'teal')}>
            <Test />
            <Hero />
        </Box>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useColorModeValue` is a hook and as per the React documentation;

> Always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns. [Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).

E.G

```
export default function Foo() {
  const bg = useColorModeValue('brand.500', 'teal')
  return (<Box bg={bg} />)
}
```

However, you will actually need to move your Chakra provider up one level so that you can do this;

```
export default function Application() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <Foo />
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
}
```